# Images in PDF attachment of a Visualforce email Template

Tags: pdf, images, visualforce-template, google

When I try to a add an image in my PDF attachment of my email :

```
<messaging:attachment filename="test.pdf" renderAs="PDF">
    <apex:image value="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1dRlAxFf-pg0XOwQ293ypAXZ1g4HGKzTC"/>
</messaging:attachment>
```

The image is not displayed.

Why ?

Comment: I assume it is because your image is not publicly available. Try adding the image as a externally available document in Salesforce and referencing that.

Comment: My image is accessible in public, I usually use these links to put pictures on forum.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-images-stored-as-static-resources-cannot-be-seen-in-emails-sent-using-VF-email-templates-1327108316482&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: can you try use `https://doc-00-2k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/5uvdfm5iu40t7gj9as9daqi3f6e597n3/1529078400000/03456987841964459010/*/1dRlAxFf-pg0XOwQ293ypAXZ1g4HGKzTCz `

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that PDF rendering doesn’t support images encoded in the 'data: URI' scheme format. See [Adding Attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_attachments.htm). You've not set the image link in CORS, so the render engine doesn't view it as being safe/secure content. If you want it to render properly, you preferably want to set it up as a static resource.